# Can keras/tensorflow only handle fixed size input per batch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to create a network that can read arbitrary strings and make a numeric prediction. I can create arbitrary stings and feed it into the network, but only string by string. It seems not possible to create a batch of strings. Is that correct? When I increase the batch size in the example, I get an error. So, if I wanted to batches for training, I would need to group them into strings of fixed size? Or am I missing something? Is it just keras? Do I have the same limitation in tensorflow? Is there a better way to do this?
[Here](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/tutorials/nlp/cnn.html) someone is using a convolutional network to do something along these lines (sentiment prediction). Though they pad the input sentences to have all the same length. I wonder whether there are architectures to go around this.

```
%pylab inline
import random
import string
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import LSTM, TimeDistributed, Dense, SimpleRNN

BATCH_SIZE = 1
NAMESPACE = string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits
NAMESPACELENGTH = len(NAMESPACE)

def generate_encoding():
    encoding = {}
    for i, letter in enumerate(NAMESPACE):
        encoding[letter] = i
    return encoding

ENCODING = generate_encoding()

def letter_to_vec(letter):
    vec = np.zeros(NAMESPACELENGTH)
    vec[ENCODING[letter]] = 1
    return vec

def word_to_matrix(word):
    return np.array([letter_to_vec(letter) for letter in word])

def dummy_X_y(size=BATCH_SIZE):
    X = []
    y = []
    for N in np.random.randint(1, 100, size):
        tmp = ''.join(random.choice(NAMESPACE) for _ in range(N))
        X.append(tmp)
        y.append(len(tmp))
        del tmp
    return X, y

print(dummy_X_y())


def generate_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(SimpleRNN(1, input_shape=(None, NAMESPACELENGTH), return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
                  optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
    return model

model = generate_model()

for _ in range(20000):
    # train LSTM
    # generate new random sequence
    X,y = dummy_X_y(size=BATCH_SIZE)
    X = np.array([word_to_matrix(x) for x in X])
    # fit model for one epoch on this sequence
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the overall idea correct: **sentences in each batch need to be fixed length**. Why? Because the network is really just a graph of tensor operations and you need those tensors to have a fixed shape. To simplify, what you are asking is a matrix where each row might have different number of columns; this is not possible so in a similar fashion batches of varying length sentences get padded. This is also the case for any tensor library, try creating a matrix with varying number of columns for every row in NumPy.

Sentences in different batches can have different max lengths. We [Mask](https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking) the padded sequences so the RNN layers simply ignore them. The result is they process varying lengths by skipping the padded entries. Keras also has [utility functions](https://keras.io/preprocessing/sequence/) for padding, one-hot encoding etc.

You can avoid padding if you use batch size of 1 but most gradient descent algorithms will not behave as well, especially if the data is noisy.